# Java override method with nested classes generic parameters

Tags: java, generics, nested-generics

I'm trying to override the following methods but I can't figure out the generics mechanism:

```
public interface MyInterface<T extends MyGenericObject> {
    public void read(long id, Callback<T> callback);
    public void readAll(Callback<Collection<T>> callback);
}

public class SomeObject extends MyGenericObject {
    ...
}

public class MyClass implements MyInterface<SomeObject> {
    @Override
    public void read(long id, **????** callback) {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void readAll(**????** callback) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Could you please help me?

EDIT: I had an intermediate Interface between MyClass and MyInterface and the generic SomeObject wasnt passed all the way, that was my problem...

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I was simply going with Callabck<SomeObject> and Callback<Collection<SomeObject>> but the IDE threw error "read/readAll in MyClass clashes with read/readAll in MyInterface,; both methods have same erasure, yet neither overrides the other".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace each `T` by `SomeObject` which is passed to `MyInterface<T>`.

```
// T has become SomeObject = put everywhere SomeObject instead of T
public class MyClass implements MyInterface<SomeObject> { 
    @Override
    public void read(long id, Callback<SomeObject> callback) {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void readAll(Callback<Collection<SomeObject>> callback) {
        ...
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

You have mentioned in comment that it does not compile due of erasure problem (why you getting this error is explained in comment section), however this is not possible with code you have posted:

```
public interface MyInterface<T extends MyGenericObject> {
    void read(long id, Callback<T> callback);
    void readAll(Callback<Collection<T>> callback);
}

public interface Callback<T> {}
public class MyGenericObject {}
public class SomeObject extends MyGenericObject {}

public class MyClass implements MyInterface<SomeObject> {
    @Override public void read(long id, Callback<SomeObject> callback) {}
    @Override public void readAll(Callback<Collection<SomeObject>> callback) {}
}
```

Comment: It says "read/readAll in MyClass clashes with read/readAll in MyInterface,; both methods have same erasure, yet neither overrides the other".

Comment: @GaetanL. Not unless your code is something different from what you posted.

Comment: @GaetanL. "both methods have the same erasure" appears only when generic methods have the same name and the same argument after you remove generic type. This would be the case only if you have `read(Callback<SomeObject>)` and `read(Callback<Collection<SomeObject>>)`. If you erase type in <>, you will get the same methods `read(Callback<?>)`, `read(Callback<?>)`. Java erases generic types at runtime so the methods would look the same. But your methods does not have the same name: `read` and `readAll` thats why it is impossible to throw such an error in example you posted.

Answer (score 2):

This code compiles without any error:

```
import java.util.Collection;

interface Callback<T> {}

class MyGenericObject {}

interface MyInterface<T extends MyGenericObject> {
    public void read(long id, Callback<T> callback);
    public void readAll(Callback<Collection<T>> callback);
}

class SomeObject extends MyGenericObject { }

class MyClass implements MyInterface<SomeObject> {
    @Override
    public void read(long id, Callback<SomeObject> callback) {
    }

    @Override
    public void readAll(Callback<Collection<SomeObject>> callback) {
    }
}
```

If you are getting "read/readAll in MyClass clashes with read/readAll in MyInterface; both methods have same erasure, yet neither overrides the other", then your code is different to what you have indicated.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure you can just use `Callback<SomeObject> callback` and `Callback<Collection<SomeObject>> callback` respectively.

Comment: It says "read/readAll in MyClass clashes with read/readAll in MyInterface,; both methods have same erasure, yet neither overrides the other".

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
public class MyClass<T extends  SomeObject> implements MyInterface<T> {
```

Now you can use T in your method implementations. You will specify the specific class when you instantiate MyClass.